# Collectionview SelectionChangeCommand doesn´t work with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm .NET MAUI

Tags: mvvm, maui, maui-community-toolkit, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have a simple project using Community Toolkit Mvvm tool and a collectionview. The issue is that the SelectionChangeCommand of the CollectionView doesn´t fired when I select an element of the collection. I created this project because on another more complex project the error is that it can't find the binding command on the viewmodel. I know that the connection between the view and viewmodel is working because the collectionview is filling with elements on the viewmodel and also I am able to change the visibility of the border through the binded property.

Sample project: https://github.com/luis95gr/MvvmError.App

**Code**

LoginPage (first page with collectionview)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MvvmError.Views.LoginPage"
         xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MvvmError.Models"
         Title="LoginPage">

<RefreshView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Border BackgroundColor="Red" IsVisible="{Binding Visible}" Stroke="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="40,0,0,0" />
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <CollectionView Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding MessageSelected}"  SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding MessageSelectedCommand}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MessagesMessages">
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="100*" ColumnDefinitions="100*">
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Asunto}" />
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

    </Border>
</RefreshView>
```

LoginPageViewModel

```
public partial class LoginPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private MessagesMessages messageSelected;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool visible;

    public ObservableCollection<MessagesMessages> Messages { get; } = new();

    public LoginPageViewModel()
    {
        Visible = true;
        GetMessages();
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    async void MessageSelectedCommand()
    {
        var snackbar = Snackbar.Make("Hola");

        await snackbar.Show();
    }

    private void GetMessages()
    {
        Messages.Add(new MessagesMessages
        {
            Asunto = "Hola"
        });
        Messages.Add(new MessagesMessages
        {
            Asunto = "Hola1"
        });
        Messages.Add(new MessagesMessages
        {
            Asunto = "Hola2"
        });
        Messages.Add(new MessagesMessages
        {
            Asunto = "Hola3"
        });
    }

}
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
   public LoginPage(LoginPageViewModel loginPageViewModel)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       BindingContext= loginPageViewModel;
   }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<LoginPage>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ViewModels.LoginPageViewModel>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not following the naming convention

> The name of the generated command will be created based on the method
> name. The generator will use the method name and append "Command" at
> the end, and it will strip the "On" prefix, if present. Additionally,
> for asynchronous methods, the "Async" suffix is also stripped before
> "Command" is appeneded.

to generate a command named `MessageSelectedCommand` your method should look like

```
[RelayCommand]
async void MessageSelected()
```