# MAUI: API response not displaying in CollectionView

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I'm using RestSharp to get a response from an API. And working properly. But after I tried to get those response in to model and bind it with a `CollectionView` using CommunityToolkit.MVVM, it's not displaying data.

XAML file

```xml
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:NewAppliedLeave">
       
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            
</CollectionView>
```

ViewModel.cs

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<NewAppliedLeave> _LHItems;

public async Task<ObservableCollection<NewAppliedLeave>> GetAppliedLeave()
{
    RestResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);
    var responseContent = response.Content.ToString();

    Debug.WriteLine(responseContent);

    List<NewAppliedLeave> leaveItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewAppliedLeave>>(responseContent);

    LHItems = new ObservableCollection<NewAppliedLeave>(leaveItem);
              
    return LHItems;              
}
```

I'm expecting to display response content in `CollectionView`.

Comment: Show please the code where you fill the collectionview

Comment: Set _LHItems on MainThread only and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, please add a break point when you debug to check if the `LHItems` has a correcr value.

And then please make sure you have bound the CollectionView.ItemSource to the `LHItems` in the xaml or in the page's construction method.

Finally, I didn't see there are any controls in the `<DataTemplate>`. Did you add some controls in it such as `Label` or `Image` in it to display the properties in the model named NewAppliedLeave and make it inherit from the `ObservableObject`?

And for the `ObservableCollection<NewAppliedLeave>` property in the viewmodel, you need't to add `[ObservableProperty]`.

You can refer to this case which shows [the details about using the CommunityToolkit.mvvm and the CollectionView in the .net maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74826397/collectionview-selectionchangecommand-doesn%C2%B4t-work-with-communitytoolkit-mvvm-n).

Answer (score 0):

When using [ObservableProperty] MVVM toolkit will generate code for you but the declaration **should be lowercase** without underscore.

UPDATE: After some testing, a leading underscore is not making any issue.

```
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<NewAppliedLeave> lHItems;
```

The above will generate the below code automatically:

```
 public NewAppliedLeave LHItems
    {
        get => lHItems;
        set => SetProperty(ref lHItems, value);
    }
```

Then you can use the below code to populate the list.

```
LHItems = new ObservableCollection<NewAppliedLeave>(leaveItem);
```

Comment: That's not entirely true. You can use both with and without underscore. The name of the backing field just cannot begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: If the property name start with the underscore then the generated code will be mistyped. If you need to begin with underscore it's better to avoid using the [ObservableProperty] attribute and add the generated code as you like.

Comment: That's incorrect. You can use both notations equally. The Source Generators recognize the underscore. If you create a backing field called `_age` then a property called `Age` will be generated. Don't believe me? Check out my MAUI samples repository to see it in action: https://github.com/ewerspej/maui-samples.

Comment: Yes indeed, i suppose the sample is working fine. Nice finding.